# Android app autostart

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, autostart

I'm working on an Android application, and I want it to get started right after the phone boots up. I used BroadcastReceiver, and the intent filter boot up complete, and the permission, and I think it's working; I turn on the phone, it boots up, and then it shows the main menu, and after 30 seconds or so, my app starts. Is that the normal behaviour for it? I would like it to start right away, without even showing the main menu first. Is that possible? or is this the best i can get? I didn't find anything about this issue in google, and I'm relatively new to Android so I'm not sure if that's the normal behaviour or not. Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: When you power on your device there goes a lot of things as:
kernel -> drivers, and application layer is at the top.
So, I don't think it is possible to start the application earlier than this.
Point me out if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a Service.  It will run in the background and can be set to auto start.  I'm not sure that it necessarily come up faster than your activity does, but I think it will.  Check these documents: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: thanks! but what about the activity? does it always take that time to start when you set it to start on boot up?

Comment: I don't know anyway to make it faster.  When you said Main Menu in your  question, did you mean your App main menu or the Android desktop?

Comment: the Android desktop, my app takes like 30 seconds to be shown, and the first activity is quite simple..